# android call public method and get on success feedback

Tags: java, android

i have a MainActivity, where i call the public function of another class.

**MainActivity:**

```
Sync.StartSync();
```

**Snyc.php**

```
public class Sync {
    static void StartSync() {

    Boolean onSuccess = false;

      // DO HTTP POST REQUEST

     if (response == true) {
       onSuccess = true;
     }


   }
}
```

But i would like to give the onSuccess variable back to the MainActivity, to check if the result of StartSync() is `true` or `false`

Is there an way?

Comment: Tried to use a handler ?

Comment: Read callback patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the method return a value. Change the

```
static void StartSync() ..
```

into

```
static boolean StartSync()..
```

and then return a value from it, something like:

```
return onSuccess;
```

Comment: and how i can call the onSuccess value in my MainActivity ?

Comment: Like this: `boolean result = Sync.StartSync();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncTask and Brodcast.

1. In MainActivity register broadcastreceiver .
2. Complate task send broadcast

   ```
    private class myTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           sendBrodcast();
       }


    }
   ```